# 500 (Internal Server Error) GET and request POST from JQuery/ajax to heroku server

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, heroku, get

Tengo mi aplicación Django desplegada en Heroku en un `free dyno`.

Actualmente estoy enviando algunas solicitudes `GET` y `POST` desde JQuery/ajax

En mi entorno local de desarrollo, los requests a mis urls endpoints funcionan muy bien, como se vé en este ejemplo en mi Django Server local:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi entorno de producción/pruebas de Heroku, paso algo extraño. 
Con un primer usuario procedi a efectuar la prueba de GET y POST y funcionan perfectamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago lo mismo con otro usuario de mi aplicación desplegada en Heroku, ya el request sea GET o POST arroja el error de `500 Internal Server Error`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desconozco la razón por la cual en Heroku, se me aceptan peticiones ajax para un usuario y para otro no. 
¿Tendría esto relación con que estoy utilizando un `free dyno`?

Revisé en mis logs de Heroku [acorde a esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305049/heroku-how-can-you-check-heroku-error-logs) y para peticiones GET sale este log:

```
2017-09-01T12:34:31.053127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/post/?q=" host=hostayni.herokuapp.com request_id=acd319f7-d47d-4e6c-833f-a0ef34163c51 fwd="190.240.77.93" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=615ms status=500 bytes=253 protocol=http
```

Y para peticiones POST este es el log:

```
2017-09-01T12:37:56.512868+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/api/post/create/" host=hostayni.herokuapp.com request_id=6d51cd89-431e-4b6e-80fe-55a505433fcc fwd="190.240.77.93" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=150ms status=500 bytes=253 protocol=http
```

Ambos me referencian el `status=500` que veo en mi consola de mi browser, pero no hay mas detalle en relación a que pueda hacer o como proceder al respecto.

¿Tendría esto que ver con que estoy utilizando un servidor Heroku gratuito y no uno de pago?
Me intriga la posibilidad de que Heroku haya captado los requests (`GET` y `POST`) de mi primer usuario y los haya permitido (las veces que sea) y después a otros no, como abrebocas o solo para indicarme que si quiero para todos los demás, deba pasarme a un plan pago o `professional dyno`

El error 500 sin duda es algo del lado del servidor, pero no tengo elementos actualmente para saber que sucede ...

¿Que recomendación o sugerencia pueden orientarme?
Es posible que mejor pase esto a otro server como Amazon EC2 para evitarme estos problemas (igual tendría que pagar y esta bien si debo hacerlo) o esto es independiente y debo mirar como atacar el problema en mi servidor?

Si es `error 500`, ¿puede ser posiblemente gunicorn?
La versión que uso en producción es `gunicorn==19.7.1`

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Este es el código de mi vista que hereda de `ListAPIView` la cual genera un endpoint /api/post/ que es hacia donde la petición `GET` desde ajax es enviada para recuperar los posts de un usuario.

En esta vista manejo dos escenarios

**A.** Capturo el request de un usuario para poder ver sus propios posts realizados

**B.** Solicito un listado de los usuarios que estoy siguiendo y recupero sus posts.

```
class PostListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostModelSerializer
    pagination_class = StandardResultsPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Capturamos el request de un usuario
        requested_user = self.kwargs.get("email")
        if requested_user:

            # Para ver los posts mios y los que reposteo
            qs = Post.objects.filter(user__email=requested_user).order_by('-timestamp')
            query = self.request.GET.get("q", None)
            if query is not None:
                # Para buscar por usuario y por su contenido
                qs = qs.filter(
                    Q(content__icontains=query) |
                    Q(user__email__icontains=query)
                )
            return qs
        else:
            im_following = self.request.user.profile.get_following() 
            # Mostrando los posts de los usuarios que sigo
            # Bind querysets 
            # Para ver los posts de los que sigo y los mios
            qs1 = Post.objects.filter(user__in=im_following)
            qs2 = Post.objects.filter(user = self.request.user)
            qs = (qs1 | qs2).distinct().order_by('-timestamp')
            # print(self.request.GET)
            query = self.request.GET.get("q", None)
            if query is not None:
                qs = qs.filter(
                    Q(content__icontains=query) |
                    Q(user__email__icontains=query)
                )
            return qs
```

Esta vista `PostListAPIView` es alcanzada de la siguiente manera

Defino en el `urls.py` principal este url

```
url(r'^api/post/', include('posts.api.urls', namespace='post-api')
```

Y en el `urls.py` de mi aplicación de `posts/api/urls.py` :

```
url(r'^$', PostListAPIView.as_view(), name='list'),
```

Desde mi plantilla html con JQuery, hago un `GET` del url /api/post de la siguiente manera:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block script %}
    // Codigo basico para traernos datos de REST
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("working");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/post/", 
            method: "GET",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("the data are")
                console.log(data)

            },
            error: function(data){
                console.log("error")
                console.log(data)
            }
        })
    });
    </script>
{% endblock script %}
```

Agradezco el apoyo con este tema :)

Comment: Puedes mostrar el código de la vista donde envías la petición? una prueba que podrías hacer para debuguear tu app es dejarla en `DEBUG = True` así poder ver el error

Comment: @GermanAlzate si puedes mirar mi actualización en la pregunta original, te lo agradezco. Y el poner DEBUG=True no me sería util en ese caso, dado que el error sale es en la consola de mi navegador, no sería un error propio de Django ... :)

Comment: Me atrevería a decir que es un posible error de django, sin embargo, de ser un error fuera de django, en su orden quien sigue es gunicorn, asi que mira donde arroja los logs, si ves que no hay ningun mensaje, habilita el debug

Comment: Pues puede ser Django o gunicorn, sin embargo no se como rastrear un error de ellos, es decir, el DEBUG=True ya lo habilité, desde los settings de mi production.py, pero como el error se manifiesta cuando inspecciono con la consola de mi navegador, entonces no me es tán util.  Los logs que arroja Heroku son los que tengo en mi pregunta, no me dicen mucho, o no se si no estoy sabiéndolos interpretar :(